# In Acid-state, exactly what does $(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''T) mean

Tags: haskell, acid

For Acid to store values of type T, one must write

```
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''T)
```

after the definition of T. But what exactly does this command do?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have never used Acid-state. But I do know how to read docs :)

The docs of [Data.SafeCopy](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safecopy/0.5/doc/html/Data-SafeCopy.html) say this about `deriveSafeCopy`:

> Derive an instance of SafeCopy.

Quite straightforward, really. You are deriving an instance of a typeclass.

The docs say this about the `SafeCopy` typeclass:

> The centerpiece of this library. Defines a version for a data type together with how it should be serialized/parsed.

So there you go. This command apparently derives some (de)serialization functions which allow your data type to be stored. "Safely".